# Select id in a reactive way

Tags: reactive-programming

I'm just starting to work with reactive and streams.

I am querying a service that returns a list of products and their ids. I need to return the Id of a product based on the name.

The below test works but is there a better way?

Product

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
@Builder
public class Products {
    private List<Identifier> products;
}
```

Identifier

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Identifier {
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Tests

```
public class ProductStreamTest {
    private String name = "asdf";
    private products prods;

    @BeforeEach
    void testSetup() {
        prods = new products();
        prods.setProducts(new ArrayList<>());
        prods.getProducts().add(Identifier.builder().id(1L).name(name).build());
        prods.getProducts().add(Identifier.builder().id(2L).name("asdfqwer").build());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFilterToMatchingName() {
        Long id = Mono.just(prods)   // actual code uses ObjectMapper to covert response body
                .filter(products -> products.getProducts().stream().anyMatch(product -> product.getName().equals(name)))
                .map(products -> products.getProducts().get(0).getId())
                .block();   // for test only

        Assertions.assertThat(id).isEqualTo(1L);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldBeNull() {
        Long id = Mono.just(prods)    // actual code uses ObjectMapper to covert response body
                .filter(products -> products.getProducts().stream()
                        .anyMatch(product -> product.getName().equals("qwerty")))
                .map(products -> products.getProducts().get(0).getId())
                .block();   // for test only

        Assertions.assertThat(id).isNull();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean better way to test?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for other / better ways to build tests of reactive methods.  I also use tests a lot to learn new functionality.

Comment: Actual implementation code would be helpful to comment

Comment: The actual implementation has a lot of business logic that I can't share.  Thanks anyway